# Unir los resultados de un procedimiento almacenado a un select

Tags: sql-server, funciones, stored-procedure

Soy un poco nuevo en el tema, tengo un problema al añadir un procedimiento almacenado en una consulta, estaba intentado convertirlo a función, pero no se en que este fallando al momento de hacerlo.

Este es el procedimiento almacenado que cree, fue la manera que se me ocurrió para poder correr las sentencias que tengo en esa tabla pero investigando me di cuenta que no se puede unir un procedimiento, y no entiendo muy bien como crear tablas temporales o una función que si pueda llamar en un `join` o `cross apply`.

```
CREATE procedure sp_Proceso_negocio_ejecucion_lista(@id int)
as

declare     @sqlselect      varchar(5000)
declare     @sqlfrom        varchar(5000)
declare     @sqlwhere       varchar(5000)
declare     @sqlconsulta    varchar(5000)


set @sqlselect = (select clausula_select from proceso_negocio_ejecucion where id_campana=@id)+' '
set @sqlfrom = (select clausula_from from proceso_negocio_ejecucion where id_campana=@id)+' '
set @sqlwhere = (select clausula_where from proceso_negocio_ejecucion where id_campana=@id)

set @sqlconsulta= @sqlselect+@sqlfrom+@sqlwhere

exec (@sqlconsulta)
```

tengo esta consulta en la que estoy seleccionado unos datos, quiero unir los resultados que me da el procedimiento almacenado a esa consulta

```
cc.id,
cl.id,
pnl.descripcion,
nombre_campaña=     cc.nombre,
estado=             pne.descripcion,
concepto_estado=    case when pnec.concepto is null then '*PENDIENTE*' else pnec.concepto end,
fecha_inicial=      cast(cc.fecha_ini as date),
fecha_final=        cast(cc.fecha_fin as date)
from crmnet_campana cc 
left join crmnet_lista cl on cc.id=cl.id_campana
left join proceso_negocio_estado pne on cl.id_estado=pne.id
left join proceso_negocio_estado_concepto pnec on pne.id=pnec.id_proceso_negocio_estado and cl.id_proceso_negocio_estado_concepto=pnec.id
left join proceso_negocio_linea pnl on cc.id_proceso_negocio_linea=pnl.id
```

Hice el procedimiento almacenado para poder ejecutar las consultas que se guardan en la tabla de la siguiente forma:

[image: Ejemplo de como se guarda]

Comment: Hola! Nos crees si te decimos que no se entiende qué es lo que quieres hacer con ese procedimiento? Podrías usar código para explicarnos lo que intentas y dices que no se puede, etc. Ve a [edit] y lo añades :)

Comment: El procedimiento que deseas invocar 3 veces es el mismo?

Comment: Estás haciendo algo muy peligroso. Estás creando un procedimiento que ejecuta código que no puedes controlar. Eso es un riesgo de seguridad muy grande. En vez de guardar las consultas así, genera objetos de programación (procedimientos, funciones o hasta vistas)

Comment: Ya hice los cambios para poderme hacer entender bien, lo que pasa es que el programa que manejamos guarda las consultas así, solamente necesito correrlas para poder sacar unos indicadores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, la advertencia que ya te han hecho, hacer esto es potencialmente peligroso, correr un `EXEC` te expone a una inyección de SQL y si además tienes accesible la creación de estas sentencias, ni siquiera hay que hacer mucha prueba, simplemente con concatenar cualquier sentencia maliciosa antes del `select` alcanza.

Dicho esto, ¿Cómo resolver lo que preguntas?, lo más fácil y seguro sería:

1. Modificar el SP para que inserte en esta tabla en vez de retornar los resultados
2. Crear una tabla temporal con la estructura de lo que retorna el SP
3. Ejecutar el SP
4. Usar la temporal como cualquier otra tabla, por ejemplo en un `UNION` pra agregar las filas o en un `JOIN` si complementa otra consulta

Esto es un ejemplo no funcional, pero te dará una idea:

#### Nuevo SP (Con algunos cambios recomendables)

```
CREATE procedure sp_Proceso_negocio_ejecucion_lista_en_temporal(@id int)
as
    DECLARE     @sqlselect      varchar(MAX)

    SELECT  @sqlconsulta =  clausula_select + ' ' + 
                clausula_from + ' ' + 
                clausula_where
        FROM proceso_negocio_ejecucion 
        WHERE id_campana = @id

    EXEC  'INSERT INTO #TemporalResultados (col1, col2, col3) ' + @sqlconsulta

    RETURN 0
```

- Lo principal es que agregamos la sentencia de inserción `INSERT INTO #TemporalResultados (col1, col2, col3)` a la consulta. Las columnas deberán ser las que devuelva el `select` de modo que la sentencia termine siendo NSERT INTO #TemporalResultados (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ...`
- Es preferible para estos casos usar el `varchar(MAX)` o el `nvarchar(MAX)`, 5000 caracteres pueden completarse con alguna sentencia mas o menos compleja

#### Ejecución

```
CREATE TABLE #TemporalResultados (
    col1    VARCHAR(MAX),
    col2    VARCHAR(MAX),
    col3    VARCHAR(MAX)
)

EXEC sp_Proceso_negocio_ejecucion_lista_en_temporal @id = 1


SELECT *
    FROM  #TemporalResultados

DROP TABLE #TemporalResultados
```

- Creamos un temporal de sesión `#TemporalResultados` definir bien los mismos campos de la consulta, lo que puse es solo un ejemplo
- Se invoca el SP y en el contexto de la conexión activa, se insertarán los resultados en esta tabla que es "visible" fuera del SP
- Como buena práctica, una vez que dejamos de usar la temporal se "dropea", aunque las temporales de sesión desaparecen cuando se cierra la conexión activa.